# Ionic 2 http post request remove default headers

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2. I make a http post request to my Spring Rest-api. As header I need to set the `'content-type': 'application/json'`, but the Ionic 2 sets automatically the `content-type` to `application/json; charset=UTF-8`, which is causing my REST service to respond with 415 status.

Here is my code:

```
register(user: User){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(apiUrl + 'users', user, {headers:headers})
        .then((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null , 2));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(headers, null, 2));
        });
}
```

Here is the error I get when making the post request:

```
[00:46:35]  error opening ws message: {"category":"console","type":"log","data":["error:
        ",{"status":415,"url":"**MY_URL**","headers":{"x-android-received-millis":"1512686795738","x-frame-options":"DENY","pragma":"no-cache","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","date":"Thu,
        07 Dec 2017 22:46:35 GMT","strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains","via":"1.1
        vegur","connection":"keep-alive","x-android-sent-millis":"1512686795652","cache-control":"no-cache,
        no-store, max-age=0,
        must-revalidate","transfer-encoding":"chunked","server":"Cowboy","x-android-response-source":"NETWORK
        415","x-android-selected-protocol":"http/1.1","expires":"0","x-xss-protection":"1;
        mode=block"},"error":"{\"timestamp\":1512686795600,\"status\":415,\"error\":\"Unsupported Media
        Type\",\"exception\":\"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException\",\"message\":\"Content
        type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported\",\"path\":\"/api/users\"}"}]}
```

Check please in the error logs, the headers object. How can I leave only `'content-type': 'application/json'`?

Thank you very much!